# or statement optimisation in android

Tags: android, if-statement

i have two list: list1,list2. i traversal two list and combine them into one list. then i use such statement:

```
if(list1 != null && list2 != null)
{
  int i=0,j=0;     
 while(i<list1.size() || j<list2.size())   
{

if((j>=list2.size()) || (curFormater.parse(list1.get(i).RecordDate).compareTo(curFormater.parse(list2.get(j).RecordDate)) < 0))                {
    .....                   
i++;      

    }
    else if((i>=list1.size()) || (curFormater.parse(list1.get(i).RecordDate).compareTo(curFormater.parse(list2.get(j).RecordDate)) < 0))
    {
    .....


j++;

}


....

    }
```

in these two if-statements, when `j>=list2.size()` or `i>=list1.size()`, the latter condition should not be judged,but the JAVA compiler seems all judge them and throw `IndexOutOfBoundsExceptio`n. How can i let java not excute latter condition judgement?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well I would work on the readability of your code first...

Answer (score 0):

When you want to merge two lists that have different size, the index for the smallest list will always finish iterate earlier than the largest list, so you have to use the `&&` operator.

```
if(list1 != null && list2 != null)
{ 
  int i=0,j=0;     
  while(i<list1.size() && j<list2.size())   
  {
      // your code
      i++; 
      j++;
  }
  // when one of them arrived to end of list to loop will not be executed so you need to check
  // those conditions
 while (i > list.size() && j < list.size())
 {
       // your code
       j++;
 }
 while (i < list.size() && j > list.size())
 {
       // your code
      i++;
 }
```

so for optimization, the Time complexity will always O(m+n) if you assume that there are `m` elements in list1 and `n` elements in list2, only Two while loops will be executed

**Edit**

`OR` and `AND` operators are `Binary Operators`, which means they must check the two 
conditions that they are combine, while `Not` is Unary which alwyas need one condition to check..
If you heard about Truth Tables of those operators, so the compilers are programmed to work based on those truth tables, when he see the || (or operator) he checks the conditions with the truth table of OR, when he see && (and operator) he checks the conditions with the truth table of AND. 
And since both OR and AND are binary operators both of the condition will be 'juded' even 
one of them is true.

**OR Truth Table**

(assume that A and B are statemnts  (conditions) and R is the result
 when you do OR on them

```
-------------------------
   A   |   B   |  R 
------------------------- 
  True | True  |  True  
-------------------------
  True | False |  True  
-------------------------
  False| True  |  True
------------------------- 
  False| False |  False
-------------------------  
 // so in Or table, when both of the conditions are false the result is False
 // while when one of them is true the result is True
```

**And Truth Table**

(assume that A and B are statemnts  (conditions) and R is the result
 when you do And on them

```
-------------------------
   A   |   B   |  R 
------------------------- 
  True | True  |  True  
-------------------------
  True | False |  False  
-------------------------
  False| True  |  False
------------------------- 
  False| False |  False
-------------------------  
// so in And table, when both of the conditions are true the result is True
// while when one of them is false the result is False
```

I hope now you understand why the two conditions must be checked even if one of 
them is true.. 
For example, lets say you have two conditions A and B and you do OR on them and assume A is false

```
if (A || B)
// some code here
```

in that case it depends in condition B, if B is false the code will not be executed,
if B is true the code will be executed..

I know you asked why if A is true it is still checking the B condition, so it's because
that OR is a binary operator..

Comment: the other ways to do the same merge work is another question. what confuse me is why in an or-statement, the latter condition still be judged while the former condition is true. Could you tell me the reason? Thanks in advance a lot!